# Can I use the latest version of ICS gapps without using the latest ICS?

Tags: aokp, google-apps

I'm using AOKP M5 on my SGS (it didn't have a I when I bought it). I'm using the version of gapps that was available when I installed AOKP. 
I got a notification that there's a new version of gapps. Is it safe to install it over the current AOKP,or are there any dependencies I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5):

As long as the gapps pack API number requirement is equal or lower then the rom API number they should work

Comment: Correct. ICS 4.0 has API level 14 while 4.0.3+ has level 15. If you have the latter, just install them.

Comment: or as @bigbadonk420 said, just update them with the market